# How can I get my spring boot controller to read the body of my http request to an object if the http request has content type urlencoded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I am new to spring and spring boot and have set up a simple controller that can read http requests to an object if there is a header set setting the content-type to `application/json`.

However, when I do not set the content type in a header, this does not work and I get the error: `"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"`. I understand that at no point have I told the controller that I actually want the it to read the body as JSON rather than as urlencoded and I'm looking for a way of doing this.

I have experimented with the `@RequestBody`, `@RequestParam` and `@ResponseBody` annotations but so far have had no luck.

I have also looked at overriding the `WebMvcConfigurer.configureContentNegotiation` method by setting default and other media-types but am less clear on what I am doing here.

Here is my simple controller in its current form

```java
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Greeting postGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting body) {
        return new Greeting(body.getId(),"hello " + body.getContent());
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor for my greeting class for reference:

```java
public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}
```

The body of my request is `'{"id":10, "content": "world"}'`

Ideally, I would like to find a way to be able to process an http request with no content type header set (so presumably defaulting to form-urlencoded) as JSON so that there is less to think about when setting up the post request and the controller is less brittle.

Comment: If that is really the body of your request, then it is a JSON body, and the content type should be application/json, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use the correct content type. Why do you use an incorrect one?

Comment: @JBNizet the idea is that the controller would be able to handle both 1) if the http request had the content-type specified in a header or 2) if it was not specified.

Comment: Agreed with @JBNizet. The content type has a sense : making the way to communicate data clear between the client and the server. What you try to implement  : messy/loose content type is both non standard and a non sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @RestController
    public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<String> postGreeting(@RequestBody Greeting body) {
        //SETGREETING()
        return new HttpEntity<String>("data has been saved");
    }
}
```

And don't forget to accept application/json header.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code 
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

```
  public class GreetingController {
      @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting",
              method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public Greeting postGreeting(@ModelAttribute Greeting body) {
          return new Greeting(body.getId(),"hello " + body.getContent());
      }
  }
```